# What will be the determinant of P?

Tags: matrices, determinant, matrix-equations

[image]

Proceeding as per the given equation,

PAP' = -A'

det(PAP') = det(-A') which equals,

det(P)det(A)det(P') = - det(A')
Now since, det(X)=det(X'), I have the following equation as a result.

(det(P)^2) = -1

How does this corresponds to the above equations?
Did I proceed correctly?

Comment: Is $A $ assumed invertible ? Because you need it to divide by $det (A) $.

Comment: If $A$ were the zero matrix, then $P$ could be literally anything and have any determinant.

Comment: Independent of whether $A$ is $0$, invertible or not. If $P$ is a solution to the equation $PAP^t = -A^t$, so does $-P$. this implies if $k$ is a possible value of $\det P$, so does $-k$. This rules out  choices $A,B,C$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\det(A)\neq0$, then you got that $\det^2(P)=-1$, which is impossible. Therefore, $\det(A)=0$. So $\det(P)$ can be any real number.